# C# 8 using var when object variable is not used

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, .net-standard, c#-8.0

C# 8 has neat syntactic sugar for `using` blocks e.g.:

```
using var transaction = CreateTransaction();
```

Transaction object is disposed at the end of the visibility scope.

**Question**: can I somehow still use it without variable declaration, something like:

```
using CreateTransaction();
```

I looked into [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-8#using-declarations), also tried the "discard" underscore variable name:

```
using var _ = CreateTransaction();
```

It works but it's not very elegant. Any better ways that I don't know of? Thanks!

Comment: I think `_` is your only choice. This is a language level thing, so you can't do much about it.

Comment: Or go back to using a block, of course.

Comment: You should declare variable anyway, otherwise there is no instance to call `Dispose()` at the end of scope

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski: There's an *instance*, just not a *variable* (in the source code). The equivalent code with a block - `using (CreateTransaction()) { ... }` is fine, and will dispose of the transaction appropriately. (Just because you can't refer to it in the source code doesn't mean the compiler can't refer to it in the IL.)

Comment: @JonSkeet that's right. I'd love to be able to do `using CreateTransaction();` in the new version of C#. I don't see any issues with this syntax. Fingers crossed.

Comment: @Andrei did you try `using  _ = CreateTransaction();` using var with the `discard` variable is just using a variable, otherwise you're not using the discard

Comment: @johnny5 that doesn't compile

Comment: @Chronicle, yup, then you can't use the discard operator you can only name a variable to reflect that

Answer (score 2):

It's either

```cs
using var _ = CreateTransaction();
```

or

```cs
using (CreateTransaction())
{
...
}
```

Or C# >8 :-)

Comment: Also `using (CreateTransaction()) ;`.

Comment: `using (CreateTransaction());` will dispose immediately, as opposed to `using var _` which disposes when the current block leaves scope.